# How to get data from a 2d array in the diagnal from top right to left bottom only?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the sum of the elements going diagnal on my array.

```
public static int biggest(int[][] grid, int big)
{
int total=0;
    for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {

        }
    }


return total;
}
```

Comment: input and expected output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would work because the row and column will always be the same in a diagnal line:

```
public static int biggest(int[][] grid, int big)
{
int total=0;
    for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {

            if (r==c) {
               total+=grid[r][c];
            }
        }
    }


return total;
}
```

Comment: Are you the same person as the poster of the question?

Answer (score 0):

What you wanna do is increment row and column counters simultaneously so that only diagonal of array is traversed.It should be something like this:

```
public static int biggest(int[][] grid, int big)
{
int total=0;
    for (int r = 0,int c = 0; r < grid.length &&  c < grid[r].length; r++,c++) {
       total+=grid[r][c];
    }


return total;
}
```